# Decrypt and encrypt string in loops

Tags: delphi, loops, for-loop, pascal

I wrote a small program that will encrypt and decrypt some string given by the user.

The encrypt function is working! But now I have to decrypt it. My problem is I can't really imagine how to achieve this step.

Here is my code for encrypt:

```
function encrypt(origin: string; cols: byte; fillChar: char): string;
var
  a, c, d, e, rest, restfill, langewort: integer;
  temp1, temp2: string;
begin
  langewort := length(origin);
  rest := length(origin) mod cols;
  restfill := cols - rest;

  if (rest = 0) then
    restfill := cols - 1
  else
  begin
    for c := 1 to restfill do
    begin
      origin := origin + fillChar;
    end;
  end;

  temp1 := '';

  for d := 1 to cols do
  begin
    for e := 0 to restfill - 1 do
    begin
      temp1 := temp1 + origin[d + cols * e];
    end;
  end;
  encrypt := temp1;
end;
```

Lets say we use this string Stringnum , after encrypting it we have this: Snmtg$rn$iu$
The decrypt function have to reverse it and remove the fillChar.

I would start with:

```
function decrypt(origin: string; cols: byte; fillChar: char): string;
var
  a, c, d, e, rest, restfill, langewort: integer;
  temp1, temp2: string;
begin
  langewort := length(origin);
  rest := length(origin) mod cols;
  restfill := cols - rest;

  if (rest = 0) then
    restfill := cols - 1
  else
  begin
    for c := 1 to restfill do
    begin
      origin := origin + fillChar;
    end;
  end;

  temp1 := '';

  for d := 1 to cols do
  begin
    for e := 0 to restfill - 1 do
    begin
      temp1 := temp1 + origin[d - cols * e]; //<- change made here ?
    end;
  end;
  decrypt := temp1;
end;
```

Comment: Did you try it? What's going wrong? Please add exactly what you're trying to do and why the code you've posted doesn't work, or mark the decrypt function as pseudocode if that's what it is.

Comment: The problem of your decrypt method is that the rest variable won't be the same as it was in encrypt function because it is calculated from the length of the origin string which is now bigger due to additional characters added to it during the encryption process. So you should probably reserve one of the characters in encrypted string to store the length of the original string.

Comment: Step one is to learn the difference between text and binary

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see how encrypt can work properly. I think you have given one example that does work. Cols = 4 presumibly, But if you tried Stringnu, restfill would still be 3, giving you an 11 char string instead of 12, so origin[ 4 + 2 * 4] (origin[d+restfill*e] with d & e at their max) would attempt to read beyond end of the string. Also your algorithm really worked most of decrypt would be unnecessary, because the length or origin is known to be a multiple of cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding my comment above, here is a general helper. Your encryption is essentially designed to produce an anagram of the original and you use string concatenation which ties you to doing things in a certain order. If you rearranged your code a bit like this

```
  SetLength( Temp1, Length( Origin )); // or cheat with Temp1 := origin


  for d := 1 to cols do
  begin
    for e := 0 to restfill - 1 do
    begin
      temp1[ (d-1) * restfill + e + 1] := origin[d + cols * e];
    end;
  end;
```

you are essentially doing the same thing, but order is less important and the reverse algorithm becomes more obvious

```
  SetLength( Temp1, Length( Origin )); // or cheat with Temp1 := origin


  for d := 1 to cols do
  begin
    for e := 0 to restfill - 1 do
    begin
      temp1[d + cols * e] := origin[ (d-1) * restfill + e + 1];
    end;
  end;  //(the meaning of temp1 and origin is reversed of course)
```

This does not fill the string in the 'right order' but that does not matter since we are now treating the string as an array of char.

Note that this does *not* solve your underlying problem with the original code.